# Connect to database via .pem

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

How I can connect to mysql server via .pem file?

In *config/database.yml* I placed:

```
host: 50.16.210.177
username: root
password:
```

So, how I can include my .pem file to database connection?

Otherwise, I get something like this:
*Access denied for user 'root'@'usr-109-236-98-211.telix.ru' (using password: NO)*

Answer (score 2):

If you're talking about the ssl-ca pem file, you just specify it in your database.yml file like everything else.

```
sslca: /path/to/mysql-ssl-ca-cert.pem
```